# camlquery to get all link to document in library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, caml-query, caml

As explian in the title i need a camlquery to retrieve all "link to document" inside a library.

Are there a way to do this?

For know in my camlquery i'm looking in fileleafref field if contains .aspx but are there a better way?

Comment: you mean document url?

Comment: No an item with content type link to document

Comment: Querying be content type perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

To get particular document like or url, add following code in your CAML query.

```
spQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"EncodedAbsUrl\"/>"
```